# Turned undead and allies attacks

Tags: dnd-3.5e, cleric

A cleric turns an undead and it runs and cowers in the corner of the room. He then turns 2 undead in the corridor who flee around the corner and cower 50 feet away at the end of a dead end corridor. Can the clerics allies enter the room and head around the corner to the end if the dead end and destroy the undead? The cleric is in the original corridor out of sight to the undead. Or if the undead turned and cowering are attacked with the cleric out of view is the turn effect broken and they attack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. No.

> http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Turn_or_Rebuke_Undead
>
> If you approach within 10 feet of them, however, they overcome being turned and act normally. (You can stand within 10 feet without breaking the turning effect—you just can’t approach them.) You can attack them with ranged attacks (from at least 10 feet away), and others can attack them in any fashion, without breaking the turning effect.